# Update field with mathematical operation from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sum

I have two tables with two numeric fields.

```
mysql> desc cc_call;
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| card_id               | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                | 
| sessionbill           | float         | YES  |     | NULL                |                | 

mysql> desc cc_card;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
| credit              | decimal(15,5) | NO   |     | 0.00000             |                |
```

I need to update the cc_card.credit field with the sum of both fields.

I tried first with a SELECT with the mathematical operation:

```
SELECT cc_call.sessionbill+cc_card.credit 
FROM cc_card WHERE cc_card.id = (SELECT cc_call.card_id 
FROM cc_call 
WHERE cc_call.card_id=cc_call.id);
```

With the following output error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cc_call.sessionbill' in 'field
>   list'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a JOIN:

```
UPDATE cc_card
JOIN cc_call ON cc_call.card_id = cc_card.id
SET cc_card.credit = cc_call.sessionbill+cc_card.credit
```